# Clang keywords after filename

Tags: c++, clang

My specific query:

```
clang -O2 -I../include -L../bin -std=c++11 -lstdc++ -mavx simulate.cpp   -lmujoco150 -lglfw.3 -o ../bin/simulate
```

This line is used to build simulate.cpp in mujoco

As a C++ beginner, I don't understand:

- What is -mavx? I can't find the individual letter flags in "man clang"
- The synopsis is:

  SYNOPSIS
         clang [options] filename a|

If simulate.cpp is the 'filename', why are there flags -lmujoco150, etc after the filename? How do I figure out what this flag does? (It doesn't look like standard clang flag)

Would appreciate more general advice on how to understand man pages or figure out the answer to similar questions in the future

Comment: Clang rarely use combined single-letter options like most other programs. So I suggest you search for the actual *word* `mavx`.

Comment: And `-l` (lower-case L) is to link with a library. And libraries should generally always be after source or object files. If you read a manual page you should have known what this option was for.

Comment: `mavx` probably means "use [AVX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Vector_Extensions)".

Comment: Actually, I don't see -l in "man clang" anywhere. I looked through the "Options" and the rest of the page. How do you find it?

Comment: Clang is largely option compatible with GCC. Look it up in the gcc manual "man g++".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Discounting a few corner cases, `clang|clang++` accepts the same commandline options
as `gcc|g++`, because clang aims to be a drop-in replacement for GCC for almost all uses.

You're best to consult the [GCC documentation for commandline options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Invoking-GCC.html#Invoking-GCC) in [the GCC Manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/)

Understand the arguments in your posted commandline as follows:

- `-O2`

  - Flag = `-O`
  - Value = 2
  - Doc = [3.10 Options That Control Optimization](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Optimize-Options.html#Optimize-Options)
- `-I../include`

  - Flag = `-I`
  - Value = `../include`
  - Doc = [3.15 Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)
- `-L../bin`

  - Flag = `-L`
  - Value = `../bin`
  - Doc = [3.15 Options for Directory Search](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#Directory-Options)
- `-std=c++11`

  - Flag = `-std`
  - Value = `c++11`
  - Doc = [3.4 Options Controlling C Dialect](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options)
- `-lstdc++`

  - Flag = `-l`
  - Value = `stdc++`
  - Doc = [3.14 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)
- `-mavx`

  - Flag = `-m`
  - Value = `avx`
  - Doc = [3.18.56 x86 Options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/x86-Options.html#x86-Options)
- `simulate.cpp`: Positional argument, input source file
- `-lmujoco150`

  - Flag = `-l`
  - Value = `mujoco150`
  - Doc = [3.14 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)
- `-lglfw.3`

  - Flag = `-l`
  - Value = `glfw.3`
  - Doc = [3.14 Options for Linking](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Link-Options.html#Link-Options)
- `-o ../bin/simulate`

  - Flag = `-o`.
  - Value = `../bin/simulate`
  - Doc = [3.2 Options Controlling the Kind of Output](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#Overall-Options)

If you need to know what some flag `-flg` means and have no idea where to look in the documentation, then
look first at [3.1 Option Summary](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary);
find `-flg` in this page using your browser's string-find facility, then follow the link to the documentation
of the option-category under which `-flg` appears.

> If simulate.cpp is the 'filename', why are there flags -lmujoco150, etc after the filename?

Contrary to anything else you might read, a GCC|clang command cannot always be expressed in the
form:

```
gcc|clang[++] [OPTION...] FILE...
```

If any libraries are to be linked with the program, they are specified with
the `-lname` option. By default this directs the linker to find, using its library-search
algorithm, either of the files `libname.so` (shared library) or `libname.a` (static library),
and input the first such file that it finds to the linkage (preferring `libname.so` to `libname.a`, if it finds both
in the same search directory).

But any at point in the linker's commandline, it will ignore a library unless it
*needs it* - i.e. unless the library defines some unresolved symbols referred to by files
it has *already* linked into the program. So, *libraries must appear after the files
that depend on them*, like:

```
gcc|clang[++] [OPTION...] FILE... -lfoo -lbar ...
```

or the linkage will fail as if the libraries were not mentioned at all.

There are some linux distros (roughly, the RedHat family), which configure clang/GCC
to link *shared* (but not static) libraries whether they are needed or not. If the commandline you
have posted is accurate and links successfully, then you appear to have one of those
distros, because `-lstdc++` requests linkage of `libstdc++.so` (the GNU Standard C++ library)
before any other files have been input; so the linker can't possibly have any need to
link it at that point and if your distro was in the Debian family, for instance, then
it would be ignored and the linkage would fail. To make the commandline portable
to both sorts of distro, change it to:

```
clang -O2 -I../include -L../bin -std=c++11 -mavx simulate.cpp -lmujoco150 -lglfw.3 -lstdc++ -o ../bin/simulate
```

Or if you have`clang++` installed, then you should use it in preference to `clang`
for C++ compilation and linkage. Change the commandline to to:

```
clang++ -O2 -I../include -L../bin -std=c++11 -mavx simulate.cpp -lmujoco150 -lglfw.3 -o ../bin/simulate
```

removing `-lstdc++` altogether, because `clang++` will automatically link the Standard C++ library for you, in the right position<sup>1</sup>.

---

[1]If you particularly need clang to use the GNU Standard C++ library, `libstdc++`, and not use the LLVM Standard C++ library, `libc++`, even it it is available and is the configured default, then pass the linkage option `-stdlib=libstdc++`. Conversely if you need clang to use `libc++`, even when `libstdc++` is available and is the configured default, then pass `-stdlib=libc++`. The `-stdlib` option for choosing between the GNU and LLVM C++ libraries is *only* supported by clang,
not GCC. (That's one of the corner-cases.)